# How to set default charset in Windows cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line

When I open a command line in Windows and type

```
chcp
```

I get result `Текущая кодовая страница: 866`

How do I set the charset to `chcp 1251` by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"AutoRun"="chcp 1251"
```

Comment: Isn't that more ideal to set that value to a batch file?

Comment: Not. You need to modify ALL batch files you may run. And they can be third-party and "read-only".

Comment: no such path in windows 10...

Comment: Just try to create this path

Answer (score 6):

You also can run command in command line:

```
chcp 1251
```

After that, you can check the change from the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Marslo, thanks for your answer, but my question was how to set charset to 1251 once, and use it by default

Comment: Well, does it works if you modified the value in Regedit?

Comment: And, you can check the changed effect from the screenshot. And, of cause you should run this command as **Administrator** if the os is win7.

Answer (score 0):

From CMD:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v "AutoRun" /d "chcp 1251" /f
```

Next time you run cmd, type `chcp` to confirm new charset.

Tested in Win 10 cmd